# Should we allow exam-style questions on this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

We previously had questions posted from a 'brain dump' or practice exam.

Should these questions be allowed here? Or should they be allowed but edited in some way?

**Update:** Thank you for all of the comments. These and related questions have been deleted and the user notified. Sincere apologies to those people that spent time on them. Please click the 'mod' link and flag a moderator if you encounter any of this type of material in the future.

Comment: Assuming the content is paid for, it may get the site into trouble having it posted.  I say moderate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex - Got your tweet.  We absolutely need to moderate these questions.  They were apparently obtained illegally from a testing center and sold on a brain dump site.  I agree with James that we should never allow copyrighted material to be posted here -- it must be edited in some way.

In this particular case, I know for certain that it did not come from an authorized exam prep book. The authorized books for the new exams are still in progress. The brain dump sites are illegal, untrustworthy and could potentially make our certifications worthless if they continue to propagate.

I consider SPOverflow my forum home.  We've all got some substantial time invested here. We should protect its integrity and our own. Thanks for following up on this!

Answer (score 4):

We must moderate these kind of questions. Everyone taking these exams are signing an NDA which clearly states that you cannot reproduce the questions. By not filtering or answering those questions SharePointOverflow could get into trouble.

Comment: Agree 100%. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions may come from books that are exam preparation materials.

Sometimes people want to question the answers given (though, most good books should give explanations for the answers), but verbatim text from books is still copyright material from the publisher, and most likely it has been licensed from MS Learning.

If a discussion on an exam question is required, the question should definitely be modified, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely moderate this sort of content. I don't think this adds anything to the community having this style of question being asked.